# Inserting underscores in strings using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to insert `_` before every uppercase letter of a string of non-whitespace characters, unless it's at its beginning. (I want to convert strings that are in camelcase and occasionally contain several adjacent uppercase letters or even punctuation signs.)

Desired behavior:

Input:

```
AaAaAa AAA AAA
```

Output:

```
Aa_Aa_Aa A_A_A A_A_A
```

I tried to use the following command:

```
sed -e "s/\(\S\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1_\2/g"
```

But it fails on the last two strings in the above input, yielding this:

```
Aa_Aa_Aa A_AA A_AA
```

And I don't really understand why.

I'm using GNU sed 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with a single `s///g`, regex matches can't overlap (and results of an earlier substitution aren't considered for further matches).

With `AAA`, the first match is

```
AAA
^^
| \
\1 \2
```

After replacement, we have `A_AA`, with the "current position" between the two rightmost A's:

```
A _ A A
     ^
     next match attempt starts here
```

Then we try to match again, but we've run out of characters. `\S` matches the last `A`, but that's it: There's no uppercase character after that.

To make this work, we'd have to somehow match the middle `A` as both `\2` of the first substitution and `\1` of the second substitution, and I don't know how to do that with sed.

(It would be easy with perl because then you could use look-behind/look-ahead, which don't include the surrounding text in the match: `perl -pe 's/(?<=\S)(?=[[:upper:]])/_/g'`)

Comment: I suspected as much. I'll try to use perl then.

Comment: You do NOT need to go to perl but you do need to clarify your requirements as right now it's not clear what it is you want to do. See the comment from @BenjaminW under your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your example is mistyped because `Aa Aa Aa` given to the substitution you gave does nothing. And it's also not a camel case identifier. It should be `AaAaAa`, correct?

If so, then you can get `sed` to do what you need by causing it to loop until no more substitutions occur:

```
echo "AaAaAa AAA AAA" | sed -e ':x;s/\([^[:space:]_]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1_\2/g;tx'
```

produces

```
Aa_Aa_Aa A_A_A A_A_A
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'y/_/\n/;s/[[:upper:]]/_&/g;s/\b_//g;y/\n/_/' file
```

Convert all `_`'s to unique alternative. Insert `_`'s infront of uppercase characters. Remove any leading `_`'s. Reconvert original `_`'s.

If you don't have any leading `_`'s in the first place, then this is suffice:

```
sed -r 's/[[:upper:]]/_&/g;s/\b_//g' file
```